# Drupal 7.9 and flexible images

Tags: media

Drupal 7.9 re-introduces height and width attributes to images - I understand this helps improve front-end performance, but it's giving me problems while using flexible images in the vein of responsive web design.

This is the same issue as whitefleaCH mentioned on this post: [How can I prevent height/width attributes on images run through the theme system?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14290/how-can-i-prevent-height-width-attributes-on-images-run-through-the-theme-system)

Using max-width in CSS still scales images, however the height remains as what was defined in the markup. Does anyone know how to either correct this in CSS or remove the height/width attributes from images all together?

Answer (score 6):

Check out [`theme_image()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_image/7):

```
foreach (array('width', 'height', 'alt', 'title') as $key) {
  if (isset($variables[$key])) {
    $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
  }
}
return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
```

So you need to clean width and height as top level keys but also from the attributes array:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  unset(
    $variables['width'],
    $variables['height'],
    $variables['attributes']['width'],
    $variables['attributes']['height']
  );
}
```

And yes, in Drupal 7, [Variable process functions can now be used for all theming hooks](http://drupal.org/node/254940#variables-processors-for-all-theme-hooks). Don't forget to clear your cache so the new preprocess function is picked up.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in checking out the [Adaptive Image module](http://drupal.org/project/adaptive_image):

> The Adaptive image module provides device-appropriate versions of images from your fields.
>   You can activate adaptive images by adding an adaptive effect to any of your image styles.

Answer (score 2):

```
function YOUR_THEMENAME_image($vars) {
  $attributes = $vars['attributes'];
  $attributes['src'] = file_create_url($vars['path']);

  // remove width and height attributes
  foreach (array('alt', 'title') as $key) {
    if (isset($vars[$key])) {
      $attributes[$key] = $vars[$key];
    }
  }
  return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS overriding the currently defined height by setting height to 'auto' should do the trick.

Comment: I agree. This is the simplest and most effective way to fix this IMHO. Just add img{height:auto;}

Comment: This is an effective way, however it breaks in IE 8 and below!